# Find matches between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can't seem to get this working. I have two arrays and I want to find matches between array 1 and 2. The result of `array2` match should be stored in the array variable `tobechanged`.
I can find matches between `array1` and `array3` though, but can't seem to get the id of `array2` in a correct way.

```
var array1 = ["279482", "100"];
var array2 = [{id: "279482", stock: "9"},{id: "213", stock: "2"}];
var array3 = ["279482", "213"];
var tobechanged = [];

// Loop for array1
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        // Loop for array2 
        for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
              
            // Compare the element of each and
            // every element from both of the
            // arrays
            if(array1[i] === array2[j].id) { //how to compare id of array2?
                console.log("match");
                // Return if common element found
                //console.log([{id: array2[j].id, stock: array2[j].stock}); //how to get the result in a proper array?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your issue - your code doesn't use `tobechanged` - is that what you're asking about? Are you just trying to do `tobechanged.push(arrajy2[j])` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the object by looking at the other object with `includes`.

```js
const
    array1 = ["279482", "100"],
    array2 = [{ id: "279482", stock: "9" }, { id: "213", stock: "2" }],
    tobechanged = array2.filter(o => array1.includes(o.id));

console.log(tobechanged);
```

Comment: Wow thanks this solved the trick! Much easier than my approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a push() method inside your loop,

```
var array1 = ["279482", "100"];
var array2 = [{id: "279482", stock: "9"},{id: "213", stock: "2"}];
var tobechanged = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if(array1[i] === array2[j].id) { 
                console.log("match");
                tobechanged.push(array2[j].id); //or tobechanged.push(array1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
console.log(tobechanged);
```